# How do I destroy lights when I'm out of ammo?

Tags: the-darkness-2

Is it possible to destroy lights if I'm completely out of ammo?

Attempting to grab them merely boops them with the Darkness, which doesn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try grabbing stuff from the environment (car doors, metal rods, etc) and toss it at them

Comment: Also worth noting, in the first Darkness game you could destroy lights with a tap of the left trigger (I don't know what key it's on PC, but that's the grab button on The Darkness 2), this skill wasn't available in the demo but it may be needed to be purchased or unlocked some other way later

Comment: As I've now found out, meleeing them works fine, as long as you can get close enough. I would have also accepted Gun Channeling.